# Installing a software on Linux- Centos

Tags: centos, software-installation

I am a complete amateur in Linux.

There is a software that only runs on Linux. It came with a virtual machine package and every thing.

When inside the virtual machine, I run  a .py file in the terminal  and it starts downloading the software. The software file is quite large.
I noticed every time I let the software to download, the installation wants to start and asks me for the password. I am usually not there to enter and it fails.

I wanted to see how I can get over this problem. Thanks

Comment: Unless you give us the name of the software, there's not much we can do.

Answer (score 4):

Expect scripting might come in help for you.Here is a sample :

```
#!/bin/bash
read -s PWD
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
spawn ./program.pl
expect "Password:"
send "your password\r";
interact
EOD
```

Here is Tutorial for expect scripting :[Expect scripting from Oreilly](http://oreilly.com/catalog/expect/chapter/ch03.html)